# default split window layout

Tags: emacs, aquamacs, ess

I use aquamacs 90% of the time to edit `R` files with `ESS` (Emacs Speaks Statistics). In this mode, I find it indispensable to have a split window, `C-x 3` `C-x 2`, such that I can view simultaneously the source code and the R buffer (terminal window). Thus, every time I launch aquamacs, I need to perform the following steps: split the window, select the right one, switch buffer to `*R*`, go back to the file. How can I save this setup across sessions?

thanks.

Comment: Use `C-h k` and issue the keybinding to see underlying commands, then add them to `.emacs` file. It shouldn't be too cumbersome...

Comment: nice, thanks. I added `(split-window-side-by-side)`, which works on its own, but somehow `(switch-to-buffer "*R*")` has a side-effect to revert the layout to one (small) window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is  <kbd>C-c C-z</kbd> (ess-switch-to-end-of-ESS) which does the splitting and switching to the end of ess inferior buffer. I am using it all the time.

Comment: @baptiste what do you mean? If your R session has been started and the buffer is hidden it should switch to the end of it. It doesn't start the proc though. Might be good idea to add as a feature.

Comment: @baptiste Yes, that is definitely useful, don't understand how it didn't occur to me before. It's in the latest SVN now.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
(defun open-r-project ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-other-windows)
  (split-window-horizontally)
  (R)
  (ess-change-directory "~/projects/")
  (next-multiframe-window)
  (find-file "~/projects/")
  (previous-multiframe-window)
)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c r") 'open-r-project)
```

Note, however, that this is my first LISP function. I have no idea how to make the project dir parameter working. Will try tomorrow. Oh, and note that I'm using SVN version of ESS.

Comment: Great piece of function, thanks! Could you figure out how to update the function to be able to pass parameters to it?

Comment: @daroczig you mean passing folder path automagically via minibuffer? Hm, hm... It's in my TODO list. =)

Comment: Absolutely! Great, please report back if you'd have time to implement this (or have some ideas how to do it).

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of packages that do this kind of thing.  It seems that [`layout-restore`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/layout-restore.el) is probably the closest fit, but you might want to look at all the entries in the Emacs wiki under the "Switching Window Configurations" heading of the [Category Windows](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryWindows) page.